# When is the mapping telescope homotopy equivalent to the space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $(X,A)$ be a relative CW-complex with filtration $A = X_{-1} \subseteq X_0 \subseteq X_1 \subseteq ... X = \operatorname*{colim} \limits_{n \in \mathbb N_0} X_n$. It is a well known result (see for example Hatcher p.138) that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to the mapping telescope of the filtration, which is the essential step in showing $H_\bullet(X,A) \cong \operatorname{colim} H_\bullet(X_n,A)$ for any generalized homology theory $(H_\bullet, \partial_\bullet)$. Is this specific to CW-complexes? In other words

> Under which circumstances is the mapping cone of a topological space $X$ with a filtration $(X_n)_n$ homotopy equivalent to the mapping telescope of the filtration?

Adapting the proof of the CW-case it seems reasonable to me to suppose that $X_n$ is a closed neighborhood deformation retract of $X_{n+1}$. Yet, in the construction of the mapping telescope we use spaces of the form $[0,1]\times X_n$, so this naturally leads to the question

> If $X$ is a closed neighborhood deformation retract of $Y$, does it hold that $X\times[0,1]$ is a closed neighborhood deformation retract of $Y \times [0,1]$?

I could not find a reference for a general result. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Unless I'm forgetting how this works, the ideas you're looking for are "cofibration" and "homotopy colimit". Roughly, the homotopy colimit of a diagram is the colimit of a new diagram where you've replaced the maps with cofibrations: in your case, $X$ is the colimit and the mapping telescope is the homotopy colimit. Then there is a result (somewhere) that says if your diagram is already made of cofibrations then the colimit and homotopy colimit are homotopy equivalent. (I don't remember a source for this, that's why I'm just commenting.)

Comment: In the CW case, any inclusion of a *subcomplex* $X_n \subset X_{n+1}$ is a cofibration (in fact this is the prototypical example that inspired the general concept), that's why Hatcher gets a homotopy equivalence

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! The information on homotopy colimits I got from the usual suspects (ncatlab, wikipedia) was quite sparse and I could not find the result you mention. Maybe someone can point out a reference or I find one myself, now that I know (thanks again!) it holds true...

Comment: This is usually something that's worked out in the much more abstract setting of Model Categories, see for example these notes: https://pages.uoregon.edu/ddugger/hocolim.pdf Proposition 14.10 and Corollary 14.11. I'm not sure if I've seen a source that directly does it in the category of spaces. In this particular case you could probably work out by yourself the fact that $X$ and the mapping telescope are homotopy equivalent, as an exercise in using the Homotopy Extension Property of cofibrations.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, I will try :) I have one simple question left. This category of spaces is *not* the category of topological spaces, but a more suitable one along the lines of weakly hausdorff compactly generated spaces, isn't it? I ask because Wikipedia writes a functor into $Spaces$ without further mention, what this category is...

Comment: I *think* this discussion applies to the whole category of spaces, but at the Model Structure level you need to be slightly careful: some model structures on Top define their "cofibrations" as something other than just "a map with the homotopy extension property". In this case n-lab actually has a decent discussion: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+topological+spaces . This is a bit more subtle than my level of understanding though, so you will have to take what I say with a grain of salt.

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much for your support!

Answer (score 1):

If $i:A \rightarrow X$ is a closed neighborhood deformation retract, there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $A$ in $X$ such that the restriction $i:A \rightarrow U$ is a deformation retract. This means there is a retraction $r: U \rightarrow A$ with $ri = 1_A$ and a homotopy $h: I \times U \rightarrow U$, which satisfies
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
h(0,u) &=& ir(u)\\
h(1,u) &=& u\\
h(t,a) &=& a,
\end{array}$$
using suggestive notation. We want to show that $I \times i: I \times A \rightarrow I \times U$ is a deformation retract. Clearly $I \times r: I \times U \rightarrow I \times A$ is a retraction. Furthermore, given the transposition $$\begin{array}{rcl}
\tau:I \times I &\rightarrow& I \times I\\ (t,s) &\mapsto& (s,t),
\end{array}$$ the composition $$k: I \times I \times U \overset{\tau \times U}{\longrightarrow} I \times I \times U \overset{I \times h}{\longrightarrow} I \times U$$ is continuous and satisfies
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
k(0,s,u) &=& (s,h(0,u)) = (s,ir(u))\\
k(1,s,u) &=& (s,h(1,u)) = (s,u)\\
k(t,s,a) &=& (s,h(t,a)) = (s,a),
\end{array}$$
which turns $I \times i: I \times A \rightarrow I \times U$ into a deformation retract.

**Remark** I hope I did not make a mistake. In case I did, I won't accept this answer until I have found someone who verified this.

**PS** As @William pointed out in the comments, the theory of model categories generalizes problems and arguments like this. But because I am currently attending my first lecture on algebraic topology, I will have to come back to this at a later point.